# Format HTML into a JavaScript concatenated string

Tags: vim

I ran into the following vimscript snippet in a book this afternoon and it seems like it'd be really useful. Unfortunately I haven't quite gotten it to work and I'm hoping somebody can tell me what I'm doing wrong.

```
 vmap <silent> ;h :s?^\(\s*\)+'\([^']\+\)',*\s*$?\1\2?g<CR>
```

When I highlight some markup in visual mode and hit **;h** I get the following error:

```
Pattern not found: ^\(\s*\)+'\([^']\+\)',*\s*$
```

The vimscript regexp dialect is a little odd and vimscript itself seems a little alien. For all I know there's a typo. Everything after the first '+' is a bit of a mystery. My understanding is that this should convert a selection in visual mode to a quoted version:

```
 <div>
      <div class="header">stuff</div>
 </div>
```

to

```
 + '<div>'
 + '    <div class="header">stuff</div>'
 + '</div>'
```

In sublime I can do a find/replace with the following expression:

```
 /^(.*)$/+'\1'/
```

which makes the vimscript version seem a little verbose. Even so I'd like to be able to do it in vim as well.

[Edit: It turns out the above snippet works fine, it just wasn't doing what I thought it was. The text I was looking at listed a pair of these and I was looking at the wrong one. See below:]

```
 vmap <silent> ;h :s?^\(\s*\)+'\([^']\+\)',*\s*$?\1\2?g<CR>
 vmap <silent> ;q :s?^\(\s*\)\(.*\)\s*$?\1+'\2'?<CR>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equivalent to  `/^(.*)$/+'\1'/` in vim is

```
:%s/.*/+'&'/
```

It looks like

```
 vmap <silent> ;h :s?^\(\s*\)+'\([^']\+\)',*\s*$?\1\2?g<CR>
```

is trying to undo it for the current line.

So it converts

```
 + '<div>'
 + '    <div class="header">stuff</div>'
 + '</div>'
```

into

```
 <div>
      <div class="header">stuff</div>
 </div>
```

Not the other way around

Comment: You're right. The text I was looking at listed a pair of these: one to quote and one to remove quotes. I'm not too familiar with vimscript at all so I'd assumed that the first one listed was intended to quote a selection but that wasn't the case. Thank you for clearing that up.